# Raphael charts with Jquery qtip

Tags: javascript, raphael, prototype

How to integrate raphael charts with jquery qtip since qtip provides very nice configurable tool tips out of the box?.
 I have found the implementation of the stacked area graph in this url http://grafico.kilianvalkhof.com/documentation/#stack . When I started playing with this implementation for the customizing the tool tip on this area chart. But things like applying styles on the text and changing the orientation of the tool tip seemed very difficult .finally I managed to change the text and color of the text on tool tip  ,change the size and more . But all customization resulted in tool-tip drifting from its position when the size of the text is increased. But I want all the features available in QTIP for the tool tip .Please any body has clue on this? all ideas are welcome  Below is the graph i have generated with the tool tip [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve this problem by using Jquery FLOT instead of Grafico and Raphael
Jquery FLOT is really cool, easy to use and customize and it has lot online help.
I able to generate stacked area chart with tool-tip as per my requirement.